# How to install 'noble' to use BLE function with node.js?

Tags: npm

### I'm trying to use 'noble' in my Node.js code

I found 'noble' which helps me to use BLE function with javascript( I'm using Node.js ).

I'll link about noble --> [about noble](https://github.com/noble/noble)
I'm using ***windows*** so im trying to do that '***npm install noble***' but I don't know where
should i install it with cmd. I mean **which directory should i download?** 
For example, if my .js file is at C\User\Test , should i install at that directory?
I need your help. Regards.

Comment: Have you tried the linked [setup guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL9B8wuEdms&feature=youtu.be&t=1m46s)?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan yes i alr did it. Now i only need to do npm install but idk which directory should i install.

Comment: The guide gave you that info. Call `npm install` in the folder you downloaded and extracted the noble repository to